# UI not updating in ionicv2 framework

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

```
<ion-item>
    <div>
        <ion-calendar (change)="onPeriodChange($event)"></ion-calendar>
    </div>
</ion-item>

<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>{{'tasks>task-create>time'|translate}}<ion-badge>{{time.lower}} - {{time.upper}}</ion-badge></ion-label>
        <ion-range min="0" max="23" dualKnobs="true" [(ngModel)]="time" color="secondary">
            <ion-label range-left>{{'tasks>task-create>zero'|translate}}</ion-label>
            <ion-label range-right>{{'tasks>task-create>twothree'|translate}}</ion-label>
        </ion-range>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I have these two controls in ionic2 app, when I click on dates in calendar, or slide the in ion-range control. It doesn't show me updating the calendars and range control. But as soon as I open dropdown (`ion-select`), Calendar highlights the selected date and slider moved to the place where I selected it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options you can try (all in the .ts files):

1. Use `NgZone.run()`
2. Use `ApplicationRef.tick()`

For option #1, you need to inject `NgZone` into your code (via `import`) and wrap with `run()` whatever code controls the UI. For example:

```
import {Component, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
[...]
ngZone.run(()=>{
  console.log("It's running!");
});
```

As for option #2, you'll need to import `ApplicationRef` and then call the `tick()` method whenever you want to force the view to update. For example:

```
import {Component, ApplicationRef} from '@angular/core';
[...]
console.log("It's running!");
applicationRef.tick();
```

There is also a third option (which I am not familiar with), which is importing `ChangeDetectionRef` from `@angular/core` and calling its `detectChanges()` method in a similar way to `applicationRef.tick()`.

Note that these are all Angular 2 methods and, as such, are documented under [Angular 2's docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/).